# Trigger events for ajax loaded page (ui datepicker)

Tags: jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery

I am triggering datepicker on a page datepicker.html using this snippet which works perfectly fine.

```
var int = $('.ui-datepicker-trigger');
int.trigger('click');
```

but when datepicker.html is loaded to another page (ajaxPage.html), where the above code is removed and added to it, this doesnt work. How would i use live() to trigger the calendar from the parent page. Pls share some ideas on how to do this..

```
$('#page').load('datepicker.html');
var int = $('.ui-datepicker-trigger');
int.trigger('click');
```

Comment: Could you provide code from the second page? That might be helpful...

Comment: @Saymen the second snippet is added for ajaxPage.html. Is there anything like int.live.trigger('click'); ??

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to instantiate the datepicker object first if you load it:

```
$('#page').load('datepicker.html');
$('#yourselector').datepicker();
var int = $('.ui-datepicker-trigger');
int.trigger('click');
```

but if you provide your full code it's easier to help you